# What are the basic steps for securing Power Query connecting to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, powerquery, excel-2016

I have recently started at an organisation that has grown rapidly over the last few years and the network and data security protocols have not kept pace. They currently have hundreds of spreadsheets running embedded SQL queries, most of which are connecting to the database using an account with sysadmin credentials :(

They have recently upgraded to Excel 2016 and so now only have the option of using Get and Transform (Power Queries) to make database connections rather than the old DSN and Connection String options.

As a developer I have sysadmin rights to the live databases (don't go there....) as a named user on the database instance. The new workbooks will run for me, but not for other users as they do not have credentials in the database. We have tried creating a new AD group, adding the users to the group and giving the group RX permissions on the database instance but we are not getting anywhere.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a blog post or article that explains how to set up users to run queries with least-privileges that have been written by the development team  who currently have GOD access.

I have tried Googling but only seem to return MS marketing bumph, or articles explaining how to set up a query in the first place; I can't find anything on how to let other users run the queries and what their security profile needs to look like.

Comment: That's not "only", that's *more* than Microsoft Query. Nothing changes as far as connecting to a database is concerned - use Windows or SQL Server authentication.

Comment: As for why users can't connect even if they are part of a Windows Group with permissions, that's not an Excel question, that's a SQL Server question. *Did* you try connecting with SSMS? If not, you did something wrong. Probably *didn't* add the group, or didn't add the users, or didn't give them access to the database. That's nothing new either, this works the same way since the 90s

Comment: Check [Using Windows Groups for SQL Server Logins as a Best Practice](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1831/using-windows-groups-for-sql-server-logins-as-a-best-practice/). SQL Server's own Books Online contain a *lot* of information on user management. Googling for `sql server add windows group to database` will return a lot of useful results too

Comment: `giving the group RX permissions on the database instance` that's confusing. You mean you just added the login to the *server*, not the databases? Simply adding a user or group to a server doesn't give the user access to *all databases* on that server. The user has to be added to the databases to which he/she needs access.